# How to open excel and go to a special row

Tags: java, excel

Background: I have a JAVA program and I import an Excel document to my JAVA program to do some "calculations".
Sometimes it is important to open the Excel file (with Excel) and jump to a special row.

My question is, is there an option to open Excel with "a link" to select a special row ?
Like

```
"D:\Documents\Table.xlsx?sheet=sheet1&row=12345"
```

to select Sheet "sheet1" and jump to row "12345".

I can not modify the Excel document to add macros or something else.
Any ideas ?

Comment: You need vba macro to excel workbook to that.

Comment: You can write this code `Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A12345"))` to `Workbook_Open()` event.